# About the default AppBundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

When creating a new SF2 project, the project contains an AppBundle by default. Should this be removed like the AcmeDemoBundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Symfony best practice**

> For most projects, you should store everything inside the AppBundle.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html

**Multiple bundles**

I tend to create multiple bundles, e.g. I have these bundles in `src/`:

- MyProjectEntityBundle
- MyProjectBackendBundle
- MyProjectHomePageBundle

And for reusable components I create a symfony bundle that I put into a git repository and load it via composer using satis. So for example I have some bundles in  `vendor/`:

- VendorCmsUtilBundle
- VendorImageThumbnailBundle

**"Domain Driven Design (DDD)"**

I have yet to try this approach (I will soon):

http://williamdurand.fr/2013/08/07/ddd-with-symfony2-folder-structure-and-code-first/

Answer (score 1):

As @Marcel Burkhard pointed out, the AppBundle is where you should put all your application logic according to Symfony best practices. Of course you can throw it away and build your own, but it's definitely **not** like the Acme Demo bundle.

I disagree with the strategy of splitting Entities and Frontend / Backend in different bundles.

I agree with the strategy of creating your own "utility" bundle(s) so that you can reuse your code in different projects via composer.